# Vugen - Copy image file from one folder to shared directory - C Code only

Tags: c, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Hope everyone is doing well.

I'm using Vugen/LoadRunner and need to copy a file from my local to a network share.

I would like to get away from cmd line to copy a file.

Mainly this:

printf(command, "%s", dirName);

system(command);

Spinning up 50 instances of cmd is cumbersome.

I'm wanting to do in pure c code in Vugen.

Would this information be sufficient explanation for anyone to provide some feedback when they have time?

Cheers,
DJay :)

Comment: The process goes something like this: open file A for reading, open file B for writing (with create flag set), read from A & write to B till end of file is reached, close A & B; rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks, for spelling out the logic. How is file B opened if it does not exist?

Comment: O_CREAT for `open()`, or w+ for `fopen()`

Answer (score 0):

Query Google for "C" and "File Copy"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I've seen this link before and it is for c++, so I wasn't able to use this information.